# Connect to SQL Server which is installed on Server machine

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Here is the situation:
I have written an application in C# using SQL Server as database. Application works fine on my system. My client wants me to install this application on his Client System (Computer) but he is demanding to install SQL Server on Server machine.
They access server on client Computer by typing "dataserver" in run window.
My question is how my application would be able to connect to SQL Server (which will be installed on Server)?
Currently I am using this line of code to connect to SQL Server (when database is in the same machine):

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DataSource + "Initial Catalog=" + DB + "Trusted_Connection = true;";
conn.Open();
```

Kindly explain your answer as much as possible, thanks.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: That line won't work - needs a "; " before "Initial Catalog"; personally I'd just SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

what is the value of "DataSource"? change it to the remote server name and sql server instance name, then make sure the firewall (if there is one) on server permits connection to sql server, usually port 1433.